# How to display data present in datatable variable dt in gridview form in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview, datatable

I've created a datatable with 3 columns and would like to represent this data present in datatable object dt in the form of a gridview in c#

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
dt.Columns.Add("Customer", typeof(string)); 
dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int)); 
dt.Columns.Add("City", typeof(string)); 
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow(); 
dr["customer"]="xyz"; 
dr["id"]= 1; 
dr["city"]="berlin"; 
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Comment: Show your code what you have tried so far

Comment: Add DataGridView to form.  Then datagridview1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: DataTable dt = new DataTable(); dt.Columns.Add ("Customer", typeof(string)); dt.Columns.Add ("id", typeof(int)); dt.Columns.Add ("City", typeof(string)); DataRow dr = dt.NewRow(); dr ["customer"]= "xyz"; dr ["id"]= 1; dr["city"]="berlin"; dt.Rows.Add (dr);

Comment: where is your gridview ? show it if it is there in your .aspx page. if you are dynamically creating the gridview then show that code

Comment: I've inserted that in .aspx page and I've done this gridview1.Datasurce=dt;

Comment: gridview1().Databind();

Answer (score 0):

Define gridview markup in aspx page.

Below gridview has two columns of id and name.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblID" Text='<%# Eval("CustomerID") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" Text='<%# Eval("CustomerName") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

in codebehind

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)    
{    
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();    
    //populate dt here    
    GridView1.DataSource = dt; ---> //Gets or sets the object from which the data-bound control retrieves its list.
    GridView1.DataBind();    ---> //Bind the DataSource to the GridView control
}
```